# How can I use Linux getrandom system call to generate a random number within a range?

Tags: c++, linux, random

I have the following piece of code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <linux/random.h>

unsigned long int s;
syscall(SYS_getrandom, &s, sizeof(unsigned long int), 1);
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

According to [GETRANDOM(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) it returns random numbers from /dev/random or /dev/urandom with high entropy.

How can I use it to return numbers within a range? The range I'm using is <s>[0 - 2^125]</s> [0 - 125^2]

Comment: use modulus? `getrandom(args) % (maxRange+1)`

Comment: 2^125 does not fit in the normal integer types.

Comment: 2^125 would need 126 bits to represent

Comment: Sorry, I've entered the wrong range limit. 2^125 is huge! It's actually [0-125^2]

Comment: @George I've already tried that. But the obtained results are anything but random. Do you have a clue of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Using `%` on a true random generator ruins it, unless the divisor is a multiple of the generator's periodicity, which yours isn't.

Comment: @Bathsheba What can I possibly do to achieve true random numbers in the desired range?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that whatever `SYS_getrandom` uses is a *true* generator (rather than a pseudorandom one), your best bet in this instance is to recognise that 125 * 125 is very close to the 14th power of 2, and go from there.

So pass a 16 bit `unsigned` as the buffer, read in 14 bits from the generator, and perform any necessary bitwise operations on the result. This will give you a number in the range 0 to 16383 inclusive.

Resample if the number is outside the desired range: a probability of about 5%.

With a pseudo random number generator, resampling can introduce statistical anomalies (higher moments than the mean go off), but with a true generator it doesn't.

Comment: May you elaborate more on the bitwise operations performed.

Comment: It will depend on how the generator populates the buffer.